# A.D. Alexandrov imbedding theorem for metrics with symmetry

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

A well known theorem due to A.D. Alexandrov says that any metric on the 2-sphere $S^2$ with curvature at least -1 (in the sense of Alexandrov) can be isometrically realized either as convex surface in the hyperbolic 3-space or as a doubled 2-dimensional convex set there (I omit the precise description of the latter notion).

REMARK: I do not know if the uniquness of the isometric imbedding holds up to isometries of the hyperbolic space. For isometric imbeddings into Euclidean space such a uniqueness was proven by Pogorelov.

> Assume that the metric as above on $S^2$ is invariant under the antipodal involution $x\mapsto -x$. Is it true that there exists an isometric imbedding into the hyperbolic space which intertwines the antipodal involution and the reflection of the hyperbolic space with respect to some fixed point? 
>   In particular the convex surface in the image would have center of symmetry.

Answer (score 4):

The existence of a symmetric embedding can be proved as follows.

Approximate the metric by a sequence of symmetric hyperbolic cone-metrics (i. e. locally hyperbolic with cone points of angles $< 2\pi$). Each of these metrics has a unique, and therefore centrally symmetric, realization as the boundary of a convex polytope in the hyperbolic space. From this sequence of polytopes one can choose (by Blaschke's selection principle) a converging subsequence. The limit convex body is centrally symmetric, and its boundary is isometric to our given metric.

Comment: Why these polyhedral metrics have unique realization in hyperbolic space? In Euclidean space this is known, but in hyperbolic space I did not see a reference (but I am not a specialist).  Thank you.

Comment: The rigidity of convex hyperbolic polyhedra can be proved in exactly the same way as that of Euclidean polyhedra: compare the dihedral angles in two realizations, then there are at least four sign changes around every vertex, then this contradicts the Euler formula.

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering if there is a reference to the hyperbolic case.

Comment: Probably this is contained as a remark in the Alexandrov book. But when stating this in an article I would just say that the classical argument in the Euclidean case carries over.

Comment: There is a more artificial but elegant way to prove this: the Pogorelov map. It associates to any pair of isometric hyperbolic polyhedra a pair of isometric Euclidean polyhedra.

Comment: Can I learn somewhere Pogorelov map?

Comment: Yes, from the last section of my article "Projective background of the infinitesimal rigidity of frameworks" or Jean-Marc Schlenker's "Hyperbolic manifolds with convex boundary".

Comment: Meantime I found a paper by Danelich (in Russian) where he announces Theorem 4) the uniquness result for hyperbolic space (no proof is presented in Russian tradition):http://www.mathnet.ru/links/e413e4a85fd1bec9e1d0c4013398bf1e/dan22149.pdf

Comment: However it is not quite clear to me from the statement whether the case of  closed surfaces is a special case of Theorem 4. In other words can one assume that the number of boundary components $n=0$?

Comment: Yes, it is not explicitly stated if $n=0$ is allowed, and the proofs are only indicated.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev - "The rigidity of convex hyperbolic polyhedra can be proved". Can you expand on this? What is the classical argument? I found [this](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~connelly/rigidity.chapter.4.pdf), where the index argument looks like what you're referring to. It's after Equation (4.1). I guess $\omega_{ij}$ should instead be the change in dihedral angle, and $(\mathbf p_i-\mathbf p_j)$ should be an edge vector in the tangent space at $\mathbf p_i$. But Eq(4.1) still doesn't make sense, since the edge vectors may also change. How should the argument be modified?

Comment: Perhaps I should have searched more before asking. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(geometry)) points to [Proofs from THE BOOK](https://books.google.com/books?id=KvQr9l0wgf8C&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=cauchy+rigidity+theorem&hl=en#v=onepage&q=cauchy%20rigidity%20theorem&f=false), which shows that the index can't be $0$ or $2$. This completes the argument from my first link.